# I want to directly call the result value by arithmetic operation on two state values

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I want to display (salePrice + manualSettlementAmount), (salePrice -manualSettlementAmount), values ​​according to the operation of sale state '+', '-'. And these result values ​​are put in settlementAmount.

And the arithmetic operation values ​​are calculated in onBlurSettlementAmount.

```
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    sign: "+",
    salePrice: "",
    manualSettlementAmount: "",
    settlementAmount: 0,
  })

  const onChangeSign = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setForm({...form, sign: event.target.value}); 
  } 

  const onChangeSalePrice = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | any) => {
  setForm({...form, salePrice: event.target.value});
  }

  const onChangeManualSettlementAmount = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | any) => {
    setForm({...form, manualSettlementAmount: event.target.value });

  }

  const onBlurSettlementAmount = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | any) => {

    if (form.sign == '+') {
      setForm({ ...form, settlementAmount: (Number(form.salePrice) + Number(form.manualSettlementAmount ))})
    } 
  
    if (form.sign == '-') {
      setForm({ ...form, settlementAmount: (Number(form.salePrice) - Number(form.manualSettlementAmount ))})
    }
    
  }

return (
 <>
       <select value={form.sign} onChange={onChangeSign}>
                  <option label="+" value={"+"}>+</option>
                  <option label="-" value={"-"}>-</option>
       </select>

      <input type="text" value={form.manualSettlementAmount} onChange={onChangeManualSettlementAmount} />
      
      <input type="text" value={form.salePrice} onChange={onChangeSalePrice} />      

      <input type="number" disabled={true} value={form.settlementAmount} onBlur={onBlurSettlementAmount} />
 </>
)
```

However, the value of settlementAmount in input continues to appear as an initial value of 0, and the arithmetic operation value is not displayed. I don't know why.

After inputting both sign and salePrice, whenever I input the manualSettlementAmount value, I want the settlementAmount value to be displayed as well.. How should I handle it?

Is it not possible to do arithmetic operations in onBlur?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer or pass in a "functional update" to the setForm function call like:

```js
function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can't we make the four arithmetic calculations happen as soon as the manualSettlementAmount value is entered without button onClick?

Comment: Whenever a state update depends like this on the previous value of the state, you must account for it because React by default does not always do it for you.  So the simplest option is the second one I outline where you pass in a callback that returns the new value for the object to be stored in form.